# Symfony EntityRepository return instance of "Proxies\__CG__ MyModelName"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Query

```
$em->getRepository($this->getRepositoryName('AppBundle:User'))->find($id);
```

return object instance of `Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\User` instead of `AppBundle\Entity\User`. What the reason of this?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `$em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id)`;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Doctrine is giving you a proxy object from an auto-generated class that extends your entity and implements `\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy`. You can view the code for these auto-generated classes in `app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/`.

The proxy object allows for a set of behaviors that Doctrine provides that you would otherwise have to explicitly code into your entity, including support for lazy-loading of properties. For example, if your object has a reference to another entity (such as from a `OneToOne`/`OneToMany`/`ManyToOne`/`ManyToMany` association), you don't necessarily want to always load those references when you retrieve your `User` record, because they may not be relevant all the time. Lazy-loading allows that data to be brought in later on-demand.

In order to perform that lazy loading, the entity needs to have access to Doctrine so it can ask Doctrine to retrieve the relevant data. This is done through an `__initializer__` property that is provided to the proxy object. The rest then happens, handled by Doctrine, without your code needing to know the details.

Comment: Please complete your answer and tell how!

Comment: Strange thing is that sometimes (like when authenticating users and calling user provider), it returns a real entity. But called later on, it will return a proxy.

Comment: Please, can you tell us what we have to do with this __initialzer__ ?

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes we need to respectively determine real class name for an Entity.

Doctrine uses static methods, placed in a helper class: 'Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils', for generating name of proxy class.
Here is description: [Entities, Proxies and Reflection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#entities-proxies-and-reflection).

In case you want to get a real class name, just use:

`$entityClassName = ClassUtils::getClass($entityObject);`.

I've found this useful for logging of entity data changes (original entity can be determined by `id` and `class name`).

Hope it was helpfull.

Comment: Please note that this ClassUtils is deprecated. It is still possible to copy the small logic of `ClassUtils::getRealClass($class)`