# Doctrine find method return Proxies\ClassProy

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

I'm working with symfony 2.0.17
I'm trying to get an object using the method `find($id)` that provides `Doctrine`. Usually, it returns the specific **Object Entity** representing the Database row. But in this case, it returns a `Proxy` representation and I don't know why...

**Here is my code:**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();    
$entity =  $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entityname')->find($id);
var_dump($entity);die;
...
...
```

**the result is like this:**

```
object(Proxies\AppBundleEntityEntitynameProxy)[4648]
public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
  private 'id' (AppBundle\Entity\Entityname) => int 1
  private 'type' (AppBundle\Entity\Entityname) => null
  private 'name' (AppBundle\Entity\Entityname) => string 'My custom name' (length=19)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure, but it's probably because your entity has associations.

Comment: Yes. I have a association with another entity but usually work fine. when i tri to get this entity from my other entity I receive a proxy representation, that is fine but when I try to get this entity from my database, I should receive my real entity  no a Proxy representation of this entity

Comment: Well no.  If an entity has an association then you will get a proxy unless you write your own dql query and explicitly retrieve the related entities.  Just the way Doctrine implements lazy loading.  Plus, it really should not matter if you get a proxy or not.

Comment: It matters if you want to edit this specific entity. but the case is I'm trying to get this entity using he is default repository and I received a Proxy representation.

Comment: Don't get your actual problem here. As Cerad says its the way how Doctrine handles lazy loading. The Proxy is a subclass of your entity, so you can still edit it the way you want. If you need to check if it's a specific entity use instanceof, it will also check parent classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony EntityRepository return instance of "Proxies\‌\_\_CG\_\_ MyModelName"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860439/symfony-entityrepository-return-instance-of-proxies-cg-mymodelname)

Comment: It could be the flow of your application. Of course the find() method would not return a proxy. But if that entity is loaded as a relation of another entity (indirectly) it would be a proxy instead. So when you call find() after such action and the entity was already managed by Doctrine it could be a proxy.
Otherwise Doctrine would have to entities of the same table row (one proxy object and another real object and i think that's not how doctrine2 works)  - just a guess